# Creating mysql delete link for every row in table, delete it with ajax and update table list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

So I have table inside database. I have input field and based on input I call ajax to list table.

```
a = $("#a").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "list.php",
        data: {a: a},
        success: function(response){
          $('#b').html(response);

        }
    });
     return false;
```

and my list.php :

```
$result = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = '$a'");

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
$x = $row['ID'];
$y = $row['a'];
$z = $row['b'];
echo $x;
echo " ";
echo $y;
echo " ";
echo  '<input value="';
echo $z;
echo '" type="number" />';
echo '<a href="delete.php?ID=';
echo $x;
echo '"><span class="delete">x</span>';
echo '<br/>';
}
```

and delete.php :

```
$ID = $_REQUEST['ID'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID=" . $ID;    
if($dbc->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo 'deleted';
} else {
echo "Error deleting record; ". $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

So when I click on x near list of table rows it really delets row but via php. I need to do it via ajax. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
$('.delete').click( function (e) {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: {x: x, y: y, z: z},
        success: function(response === 'deleted'){
          $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "list.php",
        data: {a: a},
        success: function(response){
          $('#a').html(response);

        }
     });
     return false;
     });

        }
    });
     return false;
});
```

So logic is - when I click on x it prevent default and calls delete.php and delete row based on posted id and on success calls ajax again to update list without deleted row.

Hint?

Comment: does your console show any errors/notices?

Comment: It's very unsafe to use `$ID` directly in your SQL query. You should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Also, you appear to have two syntax errors in your javascript: `function(response === deleted'){`

Comment: yes, I know. This is just to see if it works like this. I will do it if this works.
But thanks for advice

Comment: @Ian - corrected, but still nothing. I have 0 errors...

Comment: Well, that's still an error. You cannot put an evaluation as a function parameter. `function(response === 'deleted'){` is an error.

Comment: Hmmm ...I put it like that in other ajax call. And it works. I will remove it. Problem is that when I click on x it delete row on server side. I just see white page and it echo deleted.....

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you have a syntax error with your success function:

```
success: function(response === 'deleted')
```

When you click the "x", if your row is not being deleted in the database, then either the row with the information specified does not exist, or you are not properly sending and retrieving the POST data.

I noticed that when you send the POST request to delete.php, the keys you are sending are "x", "y", and "z": `data: {x: x, y: y, z: z}`. However, in delete.php you are looking for the request variable identified by "ID":  `$ID = $_REQUEST['ID'];`. I believe that this is where your problem exists. You should make sure that your keys match.

Comment: I just put x, y, z because it's very long row in db so I wanted to make it simple for example on so. I forgot te change in ID variable. I checked all variables and they are correct. I removed function (response === 'deleted') to function (response) but same thing again. Problem is that I generate delete link in list.php posted in question above so I can't force it to do it with ajax....